# Calculation of Investment Balance in C# or javascripts

Tags: javascript, c#

Formula

> Investment Balance (Y) =  P*(1+r)^Y +  C *(((1+r)^(Y+1) –
>   (1+r))/r)

```
Where:                          
Y = number of years invested (investment time frame)                            
P = principal investment amount (current $ value of initial investment to be made)                          
r = assumed rate of return p.a. (expressed as a decimal, so 5% return would be 0.05)                            
C = amount of regular contributions pa                          


Salary: $100,000                            
Y:  20  years                       
P:  $50,000                         
r:  0.05                            
C:  6521
```

> output:   359069.1263

Hey guys, I have this formula I wanted to implement it in C# or JavaScript. I tried a lot but I didn't get the expected output so cloud anyone please describe or write a sample code that I can understand the implementation. It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have written so far. Also show us the output that you got.

Comment: "I tried a lot" *Proof it!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which problems did you have writing this in C#, but the code is very simple:

```
var y = 20;
var p = 50000;
var r = 0.05;
var c = 6521;

var result = p * Math.Pow(1 + r, y) + c * ((Math.Pow(1 + r, y + 1) - (1 + r))/r);
```

JavaScript:

```
var y = 20;
var p = 50000;
var r = 0.05;
var c = 6521;

var result = p * Math.pow(1 + r, y) + c * ((Math.pow(1 + r, y + 1) - (1 + r))/r);
```

You should only assign your values to variables.